# Меню Уровне в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем привет.Помогите пожалуйста.Хочу сделать меню уровней чтобы сначала был открыт только первый уровень,а после его прохождения открывался второй,а после прохождения второго уровня открывался третий уровень ну и так далее.Я написал скрипт для этих уровней.И как только я запускаю игру вылетает ошибка:
IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
LevelManager.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/LevelManager.cs:23)

А вот сам скрипт:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class LevelManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    int LvlUnLock;
    public Button[] buttons;

    void Start()
    {
        LvlUnLock = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Lvl", 2);

        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.Length; i++)
        {
            buttons[i].interactable = false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < LvlUnLock; i++)
        {
            buttons[i].interactable = true;//Проблема указывает на эту строчку
        }
    }

    public void loadLevel(int levelIndex)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(levelIndex);
    }
}
```

Как убрать эту проблему чтобы всё работало???
Пожалуйста помогите!!!

Comment: код в текст поместите.

Comment: Всмысле в текст?

Comment: В смысле: прочитайте правила размещения вопросов тут. Или посмотрите, как другие вопросы с кодом задают. Никто вручную ваш текст перебивать не будет.

Comment: Ааа!Всё понял!Щас исправлю!

Comment: Всё готово!Так надо было сделать?

Comment: да. даже ответ уже получили сразу после этого.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и учебные ресурсы по C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-c)

Answer (score 2):

Значение i больше, чем длина массива. Не забудьте, что массив индексируется с нуля

Смотрите что у вас в buttons.Length и LvlUnlock. Они явно отличаются по значению

Comment: А как это исправить?Что надо для этого сделать?

Comment: Что нужно сделать написано во втором абзаце ответа. Нужно, чтобы значения совпадали или второе было меньше

Comment: Извините за мою тупость...Но что за значения?Там где написано i = 0?

Comment: Я меняю эти значения но ошибка всё равно выскакивает

Comment: Начнём с теории. Давайте так: расскажите из чего состоит цикл for. Что мы туда записываем? Вообще, по теории, не в конкретном примере

Comment: Честно я не знаю,я начинающий программист и я я учусь только.

Comment: Можете пожалуйста пожалуйста сказать что мне и куда вписывать?

Comment: Тогда вам для начала надо прочитать хотя бы одну книгу. Программированием наобум и методом тыка и догадок не занимаются

Comment: Потому что я **конкретно и чётко** написал что смотреть и править. Если у вас даже на этом уровне проблемы, то однозначно книгу читать бегом